# crispy form - Django SelectDateWidget

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-crispy-forms

Am using crispy forms and SelectDateWidget in django.  This is my sample form

```
class SignupForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model=NGO
    fields=['Organization_Name','Contact_Person','Email_id','Mobile_no','Address','City','Pincode','Website','Established_on']
    widgets = {
        'Address': forms.Textarea, 'Email_id':forms.EmailInput,'Established_on':forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1900,datetime.today().year+1))
    }
```

In my html am accessing the Established_on field as

```
{{ form.Established_on | as_crispy_field }}
```

But it displays in vertical View.
[image]

I tried with

```
{{ form.Established_on_day  | as_crispy_field }}
```

But it gives error "**as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent**". I want to display Month,Day and Year in a Single Row.

Answer (score 2):

[Original SO Post/Answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23938003/how-to-display-django-selectdatewidget-on-one-line-using-crispy-forms)!

```
widgets = {
 'Established_on':forms.SelectDateWidget(attrs={'style': 'display: inline-block; width: 33%;'})
}
```

This will display the select elements inline at 1/3'rd width.